# NSUserdefaults decoder results in NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type

Tags: xcode, swift3, nsuserdefaults, nscoding

Im trying to create an array from NSUserDefaults. The old app is in Obj C, I thought my userdefaults was of file type NSArray with the array containing a custom class called GD_Owed_HistoryObject.

I tried to decode this class and use it in the new app using Swift 3

```
@objc(GD_Owed_HistoryObject)
class UserDefaultHistory: NSObject, NSCoding {

let saveDate: String?

init(saveDate: String) {
    self.saveDate = saveDate
}

required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
    self.saveDate = (decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "owedSaveDate") as? String)
}

func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
    coder.encode(saveDate, forKey: "owedSaveDate")
}
}
```

I can get the count of my array, and it has the correct number of objects in it

```
print("\(statementHistory.count) is the array count") // 3
```

I also tried to figure out what kind of objects are in my array

```
print("\(type(of: statementHistory)) type of array") // UserDefaultStatement
```

UserDefaultStatement is what I assumed I was getting back from NSUserdefaults. So I tried to use this to create the array

```
import UIKit

@objc(GD_Owed_Bill)
class UserDefaultStatement: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var statementHistory: [UserDefaultHistory]

    init(statementHistory: UserDefaultHistory) {
        self.statementHistory = [statementHistory]
    }

    required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
        self.statementHistory = (decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "owedHistoryArray") as! Array)
    }

    func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        coder.encode(statementHistory, forKey: "owedHistoryArray")

    }

}
```

But when I try and access a property on UserDefaultHistory I get this error.

```
fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type
2017-03-01 11:58:37.411214 owed[1230:571980] fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type
```

I've been working on this for 2 days with not allot of progress. I think I'm assigning the array type incorrectly, but I don't know how to ask what kind of object am I getting back from my decoding.

**Update**
After spending some time with the old app it appears that I NSKeyArchived the objects, judging by what I needed to do to use them.

```
historyArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:billDetails.historyArray];
NSLog(@"This is the array count for the history log %lu", (unsigned long)historyArray.count);

// check to see if there is history
[self checkHistory];

// un archive the history array objects
for (NSData *historyData in historyArray)
{
    // set a instance of the person class to each NSData object found in the temp array
    GD_Owed_HistoryObject *historyObject = [[GD_Owed_HistoryObject alloc] init];
    historyObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:historyData];
    NSLog(@"This is the history object %@", historyObject);
    NSLog(@"This is the save date %@", historyObject.saveDate);
    NSLog(@"This is the total before %@", historyObject.beforeTotal);
    NSLog(@"This is the total after %@", historyObject.afterTotal);
    NSLog(@"This is the amount changed %@", historyObject.amountChanged);
    //[decodedHistoryArray addObject: historyObject];

    [decodedHistoryArray insertObject:historyObject atIndex:0];
}
```

I'm just now exactly sure how to take my array with the archived objects in it and unarchive them. statementHistory would be my array with the archived items

**Update**

```
var historyArray = statementHistory

            let restoredStatement = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: historyArray) as! UserDefaultHistory
            restoredStatement.statementHistory[0].saveDate
```

But I get this error:
`Cannot convert value ot type '[UserDefaultHistory]' ot expected argument type 'Data`'

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question works basically. The error must be somewhere else.

I tested this code in a Playground, maybe it's a hint how to use the archiver/unarchiver:

```
let defaultHistory = UserDefaultHistory(saveDate: "2017/3/1")
let statement = UserDefaultStatement(statementHistory: defaultHistory)

// archive the class to Data
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: statement)
print(data as NSData) // the type cast prints the raw data rather than "xy bytes"

// unarchive the data to class
let restoredStatement = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as! UserDefaultStatement
restoredStatement.statementHistory[0].saveDate // "2017/3/1"
```

PS: As mentioned in your previous question you are going to archive `[UserDefaultHistory]` so you definitely get `[UserDefaultHistory]` back (`decodeObject(forKey: "owedHistoryArray") as! [UserDefaultHistory])`). And you will have always a non-optional string in `UserDefaultHistory`. No need at all to use an optional.

Comment: I think I'm making some progress! After looking at the original code it seems as though the objects that are in the array are NSKeyArchived, I'm not sure if something like this would cause the fatal error or not. I'll update the question on what I found

Comment: Use my example how to apply the unarchiver. `historyArray` is `[Data]` in Swift.

Comment: What if the data is already archived, and I would need to use that?

Comment: I updated the question with what I think you'er telling me, but I know I don't have something correct.

Comment: *Sigh* Where the hell does `dataArray` come from? In your latest update `historyArray` is already `[UserDefaultHistory]` (that tells the error message), you don't need to unarchive it.

Comment: sorry, I udpated the code, I think I copied an older file.

Comment: yes `historyArray` is an array of `UserDefaultHistory` items, but I think those are archived from the old app. Maybe I'm not understanding

Comment: Simply: If it's `[Data]` it's archived, if it's `[UserDefaultHistory]`, it's not.

Comment: Ok, so I think what I'm trying to do here, is take the data, unarchive it and format it to the UserDefaultHistory class, so that I can access those properties on it. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think this for loop is what I'm trying to recreate in swift `for (NSData *historyData in historyArray)
    {}`

Comment: Once again, the error in your latest update reveals that you are going to unarchive an object which is not archived. Consider that.

Comment: Sorry I'm confused because the ObjC code is apparently not related to the Swift code at all. Just try to translate ObjC to Swift literally.

Comment: The Obj C code is from an older version of the app. I'm trying to take the old saved data and put it into the new app with CoreData. I got 90% of it working, but this last part is throwing me for a loop

Comment: Thanks for your help again!

Comment: Not convertible tells you that its not an archived item... correct?